# What do you call the technique of using idioms to form new idioms to allude to something?

Tags: creative-writing, terminology, lyrics, figures-of-speech

On English Language Learners there was [a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284328/is-wake-me-up-inside-grammatical) about the lyrics *"Wake me up inside"* regarding the grammatical correctness and meaning of the words. I am wondering if there is a name for this type of expression as a literary technique.

The expression *"wake me up **inside**"* is used to refer to allude to the fact that the character is "dead **inside**". What do you call such a technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Allu](https://literarydevices.net/allusion/)s[ion](https://www.britannica.com/art/allusion), as already mentioned in your question. An *internal* allusion, to be more precise, since we aren't alluding to history, another song, et cetera.

(One might also consider "**spatial deixis**" or "anaphora", which are technically linguistic terms.)